# Program receives `SIGTRAP` when deallocating vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector, crash

I have this code which is supposed to look for elements present in all vectors in a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`:

```
for(int x = 0;x < list.size();x++){
    for(int y = 0;y < list[x].size();y++){
        std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> ptr;
        for(int z = 1;z < list.size();z++){
            std::vector<int>::iterator iter = std::find(list[z].begin(),
                    list[z].end(), list[x][y]);
            if(iter != list[z].end()){
                ptr.push_back(iter);
            }else
                goto fail;
        }
        list[0].erase(list[0].begin() + y);
        for(int z = 1;z <= ptr.size();z++){
            list[z].erase(ptr[z - 1]);
        }
        fail: continue;
    }
}
```

The program always produces wrong output and randomly crashes. Debugging shows that it receives `SIGTRAP` when deconstructing `list` in `ntdll`. This happens randomly, but the program never works correctly. I don't have any breakpoints in the code.

Comment: I want to believe the variable `list` is a `std:vector`? ... If so, start by replacing your indexing `[]` with `at()`... You are prolly going out of range and causing UB.

Comment: @WhiZTiM what is `at()`?

Comment: A `goto`? The innermost loop should be extracted to a function. Have it return a status on which you branch whether or not to continue.

Comment: @WhiZTiM The list is a vector.

Comment: Using [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) to access the elements of a vector will never invoke UB even if you are out of range, You'll rather get an exception thrown.

Comment: @WhiZTiM There doesn't seems to be possible for out of range access to happen there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the errors I found in the code some time after asking this question:

- The code for determining which iterator is from which array was designed only for `list[0]`, instead of being designed for `list[x]`, causing `erase()` being called with iterators belonging to another vector, causing memory corruption.
- `x` was replaced with `0` in some places (forgot to change it).
- `list` was being corrupted by other code in the program (fixed now).

These are the fixes:

- Used an iterator to `std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>` and `if(z==x)continue;else{list[z].erase(*iter); iter++;}` to make sure `iter` **always** points to the correct element.
- Replaced `0` with `x`.
- Fixed problems in other places in the program.

The program works correctly now, thanks for trying to help me.